# Richest clubs on football manager 2014

Tags: football-manager-2014

What are the starting budgets for the teams in the major European leagues (Italy, England, Germany, Spain) on football manager 2014?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two links should give you all the information you need:
http://www.mypassion4footballmanager.com/2013/11/football-manager-2014-sugar-daddy-clubs.html

http://www.footballmanagerblog.org/2014/02/10-clubs-with-biggest-starting-transfer.html

Zenit St Petersburg have the biggest starting budget, but of the major leagues, Paris St Germain have the most money to spend in the first window.

Comment: Thanks, for a weird moment there I thought a future version of me with a higher reputation had answered my own question!